# iPhone - cancelPerformSelectorWithTarget not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, selector, request-cancelling

If I do this in a subclass of UIView:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

Then cancel it like this (I've tried both versions):

```
 [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self];
 //[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self];
```

The "doSomething" method still gets called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1 i think i noticed this recently too; i couldn't get it to work so i ended up using a non-repeating `NSTimer` instead. :P

Comment: But this isn't necessarily related to an NSTimer. It's just canceling a request...

Comment: Are you sure both methods run on the same thread ? Because if they don't then they target different run loops.

Comment: @sol I know; I'm saying I couldn't get my `cancelPerformSelector` working either, so I went with a non-repeating timer that i could `invalidate` when I needed.

Comment: @Dave - I see. Not a bad workaround. Might have to do that myself.

Comment: @DarkDust - There should be no reason that more than one thread is involved here. Is there an easy way to verify that?

Answer (score 1):

In the NSObject class reference:

> **cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:**
>
> Cancels perform requests previously
>   registered with
>   performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:.

Use:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething) object:nil];
```

Hope this helps.